# Find Matches in 2 list of lists of different length

Tags: python, list, compare

I have 2 list of lists, the first one called 'BIG_LIST' looks like:

```
['324','1','Bob Smith','Manager','320','T5'],['323','1','Jim Crabtree','Manager','320','T4'],['322','2','Jane Copeland','Student','120','F5'],['314','1','Harry Rice','Manager','300','T1'],... and so on
```

The second list called 'CHECK_EXIST' looks like:

```
['Jane Doe','AYT34','Y'],['John Doe','HF234','Y'],['Bob Smith','YGS4','Y'],['Harry Rice','HHS334','Y']
```

I would like to keep the entire row in 'BIG_LIST' if their name exists in 'CHECK_EXIST'.  The name is the 3rd element in 'BIG_LIST' and the 1st element in 'CHECK_EXIST'.  I have been trying list comprehensions but am getting no data.

```
matches = []
matches = [i for i in BIG_LIST if BIG_LIST[2] in CHECK_EXIST]
print matches
```

Output is Blank

```
$ python find_matches.py 
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
big_list = [['324','1','Bob Smith','Manager','320','T5'],['323','1','Jim Crabtree','Manager','320','T4'],['322','2','Jane Copeland','Student','120','F5'],['314','1','Harry Rice','Manager','300','T1']]

check_exist = [['Jane Doe','AYT34','Y'],['John Doe','HF234','Y'],['Bob Smith','YGS4','Y'],['Harry Rice','HHS334','Y']]

find_matches = [row for row in big_list if any(row[2] == ele[0] for ele in check_exist) ]

print (find_matches)

[['324', '1', 'Bob Smith', 'Manager', '320', 'T5'], ['314', '1', 'Harry Rice', 'Manager', '300', 'T1']]
```

`if any(row[2] == ele[0] for ele in check_exist)`  checks if the third element of each sublist in `big_list` is equal to any of the first elements in each sublist in `check_exist`

From your comment you seem to have empty sublists in check_exist, if so  so change to `in ele`:

```
find_matches = [row for row in big_list if any(row[2] in ele for ele in check_exist)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find_matches.py", line 19, in <module>
    find_matches = [x for x in BL if any(x[2] == j[0] for j in CL) ]
  File "find_matches.py", line 19, in <genexpr>
    find_matches = [x for x in BL if any(x[2] == j[0] for j in CL) ]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: This should not matter unless you have empty sublists? Try the revised code.

Comment: Yes it looks like I have an empty sublist at the end.  Trying to figure out most appropriate way to remove: ['324','1','Bob Smith','Manager','320','T5'], ['', ' ']]

Comment: if at the end use `check_exist.pop(-1)` to remove it or loop to `check_exist[:-1] `

Comment: awesome.  thanks a million.  i am creating  Big_List with a list comprehension from my csv.  is there a pythonic way to 'not write' blank data into my big_list?  worries me that the source data may place a blank element in the middle of the list and then its not so easy to pop(-1).  thanks again answer checked!

Comment: you can always do an `if check`, falsey values like `""` or `[]` will evaluate to False.